# Create jQueryMobile Spinbox Dynamically

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is it possible to create a spinbox with this [plugin](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-Spinbox/) dynamically? I wasn't able to find any examples anywhere.

If it's not possible, does anyone have any other suggestions for a jquery mobile spinner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That plugin uses jQuery's *Widget Factory* as well as jQuery Mobile's *enhancement* methods. Simply, it is a *controlgroup* with two buttons and an *input*, therefore, it *auto-initializes* itself on `pagecreate`.

All you have to do is to inject the markup dynamically and then call `.enhanceWithin()` on parent div of the spinbox.

```
var spinbox = '<div class="ui-field-contain">' +
    '<label">Spinner</label>' +
    '<input type="text" data-role="spinbox" value="60" min="0" max="100" data-type="vertical" />' +
    '</div>';

$(".ui-content").append(spinbox).enhanceWithin();
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/oq8npr95/)**

Comment: I'm using script# and was able to get it working. The key points for me were using the parent div's id and the enhanceWithin call. Thanks for the help.